# Do those Gold Collectibles have a use?

Tags: steam, rochard

For the Steam version of Rochard, I know finding 25%, 50% and 100% of them unlocks 3 achievements, but if I don't care about those, does collecting Gold Collectibles serve any purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope! They're about as meta as it gets.

Your only reward for finding them is having found them. As I already mentioned, the Steam version has 3 [achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/Rochard/achievements) tied to finding 25%, 50% and all of them. The PS3 version has equivalent [trophies](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/rochard/trophies/).